# Using a mix of uncommon characters in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding, text-analysis, python-2.5, non-english

I'm working on text analysis in Python, I'm looking at a range of Irish language texts dating from the 6th century to the 14th, which means I have a whole range of orthographic variations to account for when sorting a word list.

I want to sort a list which takes into account different grammatical forms of characters (e.g. fada, séimhiú, and úru) from different periods by their core words, so my custom alphabet will look like this:

"a, á, b, ḃ, bh, mb, c, ċ, ch, gc, d, ḋ, dh, nd, e, é, f, ḟ, fh, bhf, g, ġ, gh, ng, h, i, í, l, m, ṁ, mh, n, o, ó, p, ṗ, ph, bp, r, rh, s, ṡ, sh, t, ṫ, th, ts, dt, u, ú, j, k, q, v, w, x, y, z"

I can probably handle the fada (accented letters) with Unicode encoding, e.g u'á', but I'm struggling to find a way to work with the old style úru (diacritic dot)?

Does anyone have experience with this sort of mix of characters? Is there a common way that people have developed to work with these characters?

Currently when ever I try to use a diacritic dot charcter with u'ḃ' I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "csv_generator.py", line 44, in <module>
print u'ß©â'
File "C:\Users\Charlie\Anaconda2\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u1e03' in 
position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: What problems are you having treating them as unicode?  Have you read the [Unicode How-To for Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)?

Comment: Edited to awnser your question @PatrickHaugh

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using Python 2.5? Is there any reason that you wouldn't use Python 3, which has much better unicode support? I'm not trying to suggest anything, really just asking.

Comment: It's the version of python which we are using on my Deep Learning course at university, so it's the default I had on my machine to do coursework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as shown is printing a character that isn't supported by your code page (cp850).  You can manipulate Unicode strings just fine...it's just a problem of display.  Python 3.6+ solves this issue by bypassing code pages and printing using Windows Unicode APIs:

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\u1e03')
ḃ
```

If you can't switch to a later version of Python, can you switch to an IDE that supports UTF-8?  Example using PythonWin from the pywin32 module (I have Python 2.7 installed).

```
PythonWin 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.
Portions Copyright 1994-2008 Mark Hammond - see 'Help/About PythonWin' for further copyright information.
>>> print(u'\u1e03')
ḃ
```